# How to show the number of completed tasks in Excel

Tags: excel

I have a task to do list. Each task has a status of "Open"; "in Progress" or "Completed".

How do I display the total number of tasks as a number and show the number with the status of "completed.

For example I want the results to read in this format: 200/150 completed.

Thanks.

Comment: google "excel countif example" with no quotes.  That should get you started.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just populate a cell with that information as you go...

```
Dim j As Integer
For j = 1 To 200
     Range("B3").Value = "200/" & j & " completed"
Next j
```

It really should be that simple.

If you need a formula, COUNTIFS should work for you

```
=COUNTIFS(B3:B12,"completed") & " of 200 complete"
```

Replace the range with whatever works.

Also - with the way you're trying to do it, you'll need the count of cells that are not blank too:

```
=COUNTA(A:A) & " / " & COUNTIFS(A:A,"completed") & " completed"
```

Comment: this is a formula in Google Sheets that works but does not work in Excel 97 or vista - =CONCATENATE(COUNTA($A$4:$A$51), "/", COUNTA($C$4:$C$51), " completed  ")

Comment: For some reason, I took this to mean that you had a VB macro already running.  I edited the answer with a COUNTIFS that should work.  You can skip the concatenate part.  That's a waste of characters.